# How can display table Section in every page like thead

Tags: html-table, mpdf

I am trying to display table title with `<section>` tag in every page like `<thead>` tag as per below HTML script, But it's not displaying section tag 
 on every page. Is there any solution for this?

```
      <table class="zebra">  
          <caption>Table caption goes here</caption>                        
        <thead>             
            <tr>
                <th>Title1</th>
                <th>Title2</th>
                <th>Title3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Row1</td>
                <td>Row2</td>
                <td>167.00</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Row2</td>
                <td>Row2</td>
                <td>444.53</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               ...... untill second page
            </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking. There are no references or mention of sections in your question.

Comment: @Dave, This is related to mPdf lib related concept, When table has large data it  will continue in next page or all pages  with table header in PDF but it's not repeating with table caption in next page  or all pages.